# Html using php variables

Tags: php, html

I have a .html file and another .php file. I want to grab variables from the .php file and use them in my html file. I also have a live.js script that I need to run to update the page when any changes are made.

I can get the php working when I change the file to .php but then my script doesnt work. When I change my file to .html my script works but php doesn't.

Can someone please help me out with getting this fixed. Thank You!

My index.html file right now the php content doesnt show but the script works

```
<?php include("var.php"); ?>


<html>                                                 
<head>                                                 
<script src="live.js#html"></script>  
<title>MXS</title>                                                            
</head> 
<html>                                         
<body> 
<font color="#FF0000" size="6" face="Comic Sans MS, cursive">MenuXpress</font>


<h1>Cash</h1>
<h1><?php
echo '$' . $tickettotal;
?><h1>

</body>
</body>
</html>
```

My var.php file with all my variables

```
<?PHP                                                  


$tickettotal=11.29;                                     
$tendertotal=4.29;                                     
$changetotal=0.00;


?>
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: you've got twice the end-body tag.. remove one.

Comment: I removed one of the body tags and it still doesnt work

Comment: Didn't work. You notice that my index file is .html right. When I change it to .php the php works but then script doesn't run.

Comment: php code will not work in .html file You have to rename your file to index.php

Comment: Witch script is it that doesen't run?

Comment: live.js is the script that i need to run

Comment: I dont know I just got it on another site and it worked. When the file is .hml the script runs fine but the php doesnt show. All I need is the live.js to run so my page gets update whenever info gets changed. And also to show php variables.

Comment: As mentioned bellow. You need to show your live.js!

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file?

Comment: no I dont think so. Im not too experienced but I know i setup iis 7 and latest php up correctly. Then I got those 2 files in my iis folder

Comment: and the live.js file that i got from livejs.com website

Comment: If you have iis7 than you need to create or edit your web.config file.

Answer (score 2):

you need to save index.html file into .php than you access in php file

Answer (score 1):

**PHP basics:** 
Php is used to generate a html document. Hence in your html the variable should already be avalible. (Through echo).

For php to be able to run the php code. the file always has to have .php extension. (At least as default). so name your file accordingly.

Your code looks fine (except a few html problems, but that shouldn't stop php from working), so i'm thinking that this isn't all the code or maybe the problem derive from elsewere.

I suggest you look up a basic php tutorial.

Comment: Well yeah but then how can I run the live.js script.

Comment: That is included in the html so it will run. If you specified the correct path!

Comment: I guess my question is how is html and php supposed to connect with one another. I have variables in php, how can I use css to format decorate and display these variables. and then also run scripts using html whenever the php variables get updated.

Comment: remove the hashtag from script src, then it should run

Comment: I removed it and it still doesn't

Comment: Check if live.js is loaded using a webinspector. The problem doesn't derive from the file extension, there is something else at play.

Comment: Well I know that live.js works because when the file is .html it works perfectly but when the file is changed to .php it stops working.

Comment: nothing that you've shown could cause what you are experiencing. I can't help you if you don't share your code...

Comment: Ed Hasaj see the answer posted by me and let me know if it work. Thanks

Comment: I posted all my code there is. Its all simple blank page with variable.

Comment: Not live.js What code is inside that file?

Comment: in the live.js file? However it came downloaded by default. In then I have another file var.php and index.php which I listed the code above. Thats all there is.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a lines of htaccess in your .htaccess file in which all html files will be like PHP and your php variables will be parsed automatically.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: This shouldn't be nessicary? If op doesn't need the file to show as .html that is

Comment: All I want is to create a single page that shows some php variables that my pos writes to a .php file. Now I need another file that lets me use those variables and use css to design the single page. So the simplest way to achieve that.

Comment: Im using iis 7 how can I add that to my htaaccess file?

Comment: @EdHasaj I have no idea about IIS but I am sure this will help you.
http://kb.zend.com/how-to-parse-html-files-as-php-in-iis-6-with-zend-server/#.VCUHY3WSwW0

Answer (score 0):

Change your html file extension to php and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your **index.html** file to **index.php** file because you used PHP code in your file. So server runs the php code and outputs markup, that the browser shows it.

Hope this will help.

Regards

Comment: I understand that but when I do that the php works but then the live.js script doesn't as it did when it was index.html

Comment: the browser never "understands" php code. The server runs the php code and outputs markup, that the browser shows.

Comment: you can try simple js in body tag to test whether js work or not.. comment your script in head tag .. then add these line to body tag <script>
testVariable=3;
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(testVariable);
</script>

Comment: Yup that works so now I know that scripts are running fine its the live.js script in particular that isnt working.